# Update / Delete comment in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm trying to update the user's comment when the user clicks on edit comment and commits the edit form.  But when there is multiple comments from the same user, comment update request comes in, node js updates the very first comment of that user. (The same problem I have with my delete comment action).
Can somebody help to solve this issue?

Here is my ejs code

```
<% article.comments.forEach(comment => { %>
            <div class="my-3">
                <strong><%= comment.author.username %></strong>
                <span class="float-right">
                    <%= comment.created.getHours() %>:<%= comment.created.getMinutes() %>
                    <%= comment.created.getMonth() + 1 %>/<%= comment.created.getDate() %>/<%= comment.created.getYear() + 1900 %>
                </span>
                <p><%= comment.content %></p>
                <% if(user && comment.author.id.equals(user._id)) { %>
                    <a  class="btn btn-sm btn-warning float-left mr-2" 
                        onclick="toggleEditForm(`<%= comment._id %>`)">
                        Edit
                    </a>
                    <form id="delete-form" action="/articles/<%= article._id %>/comments/<%= comment._id %>?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Delete</button>
                    </form>
                <% } %>
            </div>
            <div id="<%= comment._id %>" style="display: none;">
                <form action="/articles/<%= article._id %>/comments/<%= comment._id %>?_method=PUT" method="POST">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputContent">Edit comment</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="content" id="inputContent" rows="3" placeholder="Type here"><%= comment.content %></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Edit Comment">
                </form>
            </div>
        <% }) %>
```

And my node js controllers update comment and delete comment methods

```
exports.putUpdateComment = (req, res, next) => {
    const content = req.body.content;
    const author = {
        id: req.user._id,
        username: req.user.username
    };
    const newComment = {
        content: content,
        author: author
    };
    Comment.findOneAndUpdate(req.params.commentId, newComment)
        .then(updatedComment => {
            req.flash('success', 'Your comment was updated');
            res.redirect('/articles/' + req.params.id);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            const error = new Error(err);
            error.httpStatusCode = 500;
            return next(error);
        })
};

exports.deleteComment = (req, res, next) => {
    Comment.findOneAndRemove(req.params.commentId)
        .then(() => {
            req.flash('success', 'Comment was deleted');
            res.redirect('/articles/' + req.params.id);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            const error = new Error(err);
            error.httpStatusCode = 500;
            return next(error);
        })
}
```

Comment: cann you post the route for exports.deleteComment and exports.putUpdateComment. 

And also, whenever you are clicking the `delete` or `edit` post the url that you are hitting as well, also confirm yourself if the url is correct or not.

Comment: app.use('/articles/:id/comments', commentsRouter);  
                                                                                    
            router.route('/:commentId')
.put(middleware.checkCommentOwnership, commentsController.putUpdateComment)
.delete(middleware.checkCommentOwnership, commentsController.deleteComment);

Answer (score 1):

IDs of the Textarea field should be unique.

Comment: Still not working  ---- <label for="<%= comment._id %>">Edit comment</label>
<textarea class="form-control" name="content" id="<%= comment._id %>" rows="3" placeholder="Type here"><%= comment.content %></textarea>